# Sql Error when using EF with CancellationToken in Blazor and making multiple instant calls

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, cancellation-token

I'm getting this error in a `Blazor Server App` when using `CancellationToken`  and calling an `EF` method by clicking the a button multiple times (with js, to click instantly)

> Error: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The request
> failed to run because the batch is aborted, this can be caused by
> abort signal sent from client, or another request is running in the
> same session, which makes the session busy. Operation cancelled by
> user.

this is my code:

```
@inject IDbContextFactory<MyContext> cxf
<button type="button" id="btn1" @onclick="btnClick">Load</button>
...    
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private CancellationTokenSource prevCts;

    private async Task btnClick()
    {
        if (prevCts is not null) prevCts.Cancel();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        prevCts = cts;

        using var cx = cxf.CreateDbContext();

        var res = await cx.Lunches.ToArrayAsync(cts.Token);
    }
```

and to get the error I call the button like this:

```
$('#btn1').click().click().click()
```

Reason for using Cancellation: I'm cancelling the previous request since the user clicked again really fast on something else, so there's no need to show him the result for the previous query.

Comment: A bit confused, cause your code specifically Cancels the previous request here `if (prevCts is not null) prevCts.Cancel();` so the described behavior is intentional

Comment: I'm cancelling the previous request since the user clicked again really fast on something else, so there's no need to show him the result for the previous query. The above code is an isolated error demo basically.

Comment: I mean then - yes you will receive this error, that's what Cancel does

Comment: @NikitaChayka with only 2 clicks I usually don't get this error

Comment: It means that most likely they are not instant and first query was already finished when second click came in - it is pretty much ok

Comment: @NikitaChayka In my actual (big) code, I have 4 calls to `.ToArrayAsync(token)` and with 2 clicks I'm getting 1 + 4 Db requests, so 3 where cancelled without any error,  with 3 clicks I'm getting the error

Comment: OK, so you are emulated a race condition.  But what's the actual purpose?  I'm not sure using cancellation tokens in this scenario is the best solution.  Is `cx.Lunches.ToArrayAsync` quite a slow query and you want to cover for multiple clicks on the button while it's running?  Before I answer I would like to understand the context a little more :-).

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I've edited my question, basically imagine you have a list with a pager, and user clicks fast next, next, next, since previous next didn't finish yet and there's no more need for its result, I wanted to cancel it

Comment: I fail to reproduce. In minimal test, the second click get the error. Can you provide a minimal reproductive example?

Comment: @vernou the code above is enough to reproduce it in a blazor server app, I'm not sure how a blazor button click will translate to a console app, perhaps a new thread for each click

Answer (score 1):

When you set the cancellation on a CancellationToken you are only signaling that the Task should be cancelled.  How and when the Task handles that depends on the implementation.  Cancelling can take as long as running the task to completion.

My approach to the problem is to run the handler on the first click (you don't know if there will be a second click) and then on the last click.  Easier said than done, how do you know a click is the last click?

The `InputThrottler` class below will run queries as quickly as they complete or on the backoff period, whichever is the longer.  There's a lot of comments to explain what's going on.

I've also included a demo page which shows how to use it.  You may need to tweek the backoff.  300ms works well with Typeahead.

I use it in a TypeAhead input control.  The full codebase is here: [Blazr.Demo.TypeAhead Github Repo](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.TypeAhead)

```cs
/// ============================================================
/// Author: Shaun Curtis, Cold Elm Coders
/// License: Use And Donate
/// If you use it, donate something to a charity somewhere
/// ============================================================

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Blazr.UI;

    public class InputThrottler
    {
        private int _backOff = 0;
        private Func<Task> _taskToRun;
        private Task _activeTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _queuedTaskCompletionSource;
        private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _activeTaskCompletionSource;

        private async Task RunQueueAsync()
        {
            ///Debug.WriteLine($"Running RunQueueAsync");

            // if we have a completed task then null it
            if (_activeTaskCompletionSource is not null && _activeTaskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
                _activeTaskCompletionSource = null;

            // if we have a running task then everything is already in motion and there's nothing to do
            if (_activeTaskCompletionSource is not null)
                return;

            ///int counter = 0;

            // run the loop while we have a queued request.
            while (_queuedTaskCompletionSource is not null)
            {
                ///Debug.WriteLine($"In the Do Loop");

                // assign the queued task reference to the running task  
                _activeTaskCompletionSource = _queuedTaskCompletionSource;
                // And release the reference
                _queuedTaskCompletionSource = null;

                // start backoff task
                var backoffTask = Task.Delay(_backOff);

                // start main task
                var mainTask = _taskToRun.Invoke();

                // await both ensures we run the backoff period or greater
                await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { mainTask, backoffTask });

                // Set the running task completion as complete
                _activeTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);

                // and release our reference to the running task completion
                // The originator will still hold a reference and can act on it's completion
                _activeTaskCompletionSource = null;

                ///Debug.WriteLine($"Completed Do loop {counter}");
                ///counter++;

                // back to the top to check if another task has been queued
            }
            Debug.WriteLine($"Exited Do loop");

            return;
        }

        public Task<bool> QueueAsync()
        {
            var oldCompletionTask = _queuedTaskCompletionSource;

            // Create a new completion task
            var newCompletionTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            // get the actual task before we assign it to the queue
            var task = newCompletionTask.Task;

            // replace _queuedTaskCompletionSource
            _queuedTaskCompletionSource = newCompletionTask;

            // check if we already have a queued queued task.
            // If so set it as completed, false = not run 
            if (oldCompletionTask is not null)
            {
                oldCompletionTask?.TrySetResult(false);
                ///Debug.WriteLine($"Queued Completion Task discarded");
            }


            // if we don't have a running task or the task is complete , then there's no process running the queue
            // So we need to call it and assign it to `runningTask`
            if (_activeTask is null || _activeTask.IsCompleted)
                _activeTask = this.RunQueueAsync();

            // return the reference to the task we queued
            return task;
        }

        private InputThrottler(Func<Task> toRun, int backOff)
        {
            _backOff = backOff;
            _taskToRun = toRun;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Static method to create a new InputThrottler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="toRun">method to run to update the component</param>
        /// <param name="backOff">Back off period in millisecs</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static InputThrottler Create(Func<Task> toRun, int backOff)
                => new InputThrottler(toRun, backOff > 300 ? backOff : 300);
    }
```

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="p-2 m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Clicked>Click me Quick!</button>
</div>

<div class="p-2 m-2">
    <pre>
        @this.message.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>

@code {
    private InputThrottler inputThrottler;
    private StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    private int counter = 0;

    public Index()
        => inputThrottler = InputThrottler.Create(this.RunQuery, 500);

    private async Task RunQuery()
    {
        // Emulate a slow async query
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        counter++;
        this.message.AppendLine($"Run {counter}.");
    }

    private async Task Clicked()
    {
        this.message.AppendLine("Queued Request.");
        await inputThrottler.QueueAsync();
        this.message.AppendLine("Request Completed.");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thnx, think this will also add a 300 ms delay to every click

Comment: It's not really a delay, just a minimum cycle time.  Most other implementations use a timer with a reset delay - often set to 300ms.  So that's 300ms plus your query execution time.